# Using Firebase functions in an editor script

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I've done a bit of research and i'm kind of strugguling right now. 
I want to use Firebase Database functions to write datas in an editor script on Unity.

I managed to read/write in the database during the run time pretty easly (the doc online is great !), but when i try to do it on edit time, it's not working.

I've got a pretty explicit error : "Notice that DontDestroyOnLoad can only be used in play mode and, as such, cannot be part of an editor script."

Considering this error, it seems impossible to use Firebase functions here. But did someone manage to use it ?

The only solution I could think of right now is writing a python script and launching it from the unity editor, but that's not really conviniant having to deal with plenty of languages in an industrial project (unless you have no choice).

Thanks for reading and sorry for all the grammatical mistakes !
Louis

Comment: I can't say for 100% but I doubt it's even possible - most of the plugins I've worked with initialize during runtime and need this initialization before any requests can be sent. 

The problem with scripting in editor mode is that most scripts rely on couroutines and special MonoBehavior methods like Update, Start etc and they either work different in editor mode (like Update) or don't work at all. If it is at all possible, it would most likely require a lot of dirty hacks and workarounds. I'd suggest going for the python script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's also what I'm thinking but i hoped someone had a super trick !
I've decided to go for a java script but it's pretty much the same as a python script !

Comment: Like I said, even if someone has a trick for this, it's probably very dirty and unmaintainable in the long run. It's a good choice to make a separate script, don't be afraid to use the right tool for the job, simply because you have less experience in it :)

Answer (score 0):

At first you should initialize firebase with new instance of FirebaseApp with unique name. I do it like this:

```
FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.Create(
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.Options, 
    "FIREBASE_EDITOR");
```

The second is setup references (DatabaseReference, StorageReference etc.) with this firebaseApp instance and use it only after FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync()

Overall code will look like this:

```
public static void Initialize(bool isEditor = false)
{
    if (isEditor)
    {
        FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.Create(
            FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.Options, 
            "FIREBASE_EDITOR");

        firebaseApp.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://project.firebaseio.com/");

        FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.Result == DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                database = FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance(firebaseApp).RootReference;
                storage = FirebaseStorage.GetInstance(firebaseApp).RootReference;
                auth = FirebaseAuth.GetAuth(firebaseApp);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError(
                    "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + task.Result);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://project.firebaseio.com/");

        database = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
        storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
        auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    }

    IsInitialized = true;
}
```

Initialize SDK for editor before get/set data:

```
FirebaseManager.Initialize(true);
```

Then after CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync callback you can use Firebase in editor scripts.